# Could not start mysql 5.6

Tags: mysql

ubuntu 14.04, mysql 5.6, I first use `apt-get autoremove --purge mysql-server-5.5` to remove old server, then use

```
wget http://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-apt-config_0.8.1-1_all.deb
dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.8.1-1_all.deb 
apt-get update
apt-get install mysql-server --yes
```

All are default options. When I start mysql server, it says:

```
 MySQL Community Server  did not start. Please check logs for more details.
```

So I check '/var/log/mysql/error.log' only get:

```
161214 09:08:47 mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mysql/error.log'.
161214 09:08:47 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
Killed
161214 09:08:49 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
```

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-install-db.html

Comment: @Sammitch still doesn't work. everything stays the same. Is there another  location to check error log? I think `/var/log/mysql/error.log` didn't provide anything useful